# Using Solr-Docker with python return a wrong results

Tags: python, docker, flask, solr

I have a flask app which runs in a Docker container and I wanted to use Solr with it for indexing and searching, so I built a container for Solr using the Solr official image and used it with my app using docker-compose.
In the app I have multiple types of objects that I want to index for example **type1** and **type2** and each type has specific fields, so I got in Solr, documents that have different fields, such as **doc1** could have **field1** and **field2**, and **doc2** could have **field3**, **field4** and **field5**, and each document has a field called **type** to specify its type.

I have two types of search first one is searching for documents of a specific type and this is an example URL of it which is used with **requests** Python package:

```
response = requests.get("http://solr:8983/solr/myCollection/select?q=*val*&defType=edismax&fq=type:type1&qf=field1^2&qf=field2^1")
```

, and the other is **overall search** so I search for documents of all types, and here is its URL example:

```
response = requests.get("http://solr:8983/solr/myCollection/select?q=*val*&defType=edismax&fq=type:type1||type2&qf=field1^1&qf=field2^1&qf=field3^1&qf=field4^1&qf=field1^1")
```

I have two problems with my work:

1. I don't get the result that I expected when I run some queries.
2. some fields have values with special characters like (z=x+y*f) and when I try to escape these special characters by **'\'** it doesn't work.

So, is the queries that I wrote have something wrong and is there any article or tutorial that could help me because I searched a lot in the documentation and the internet but I couldn't find I way to solve my problems.

**Note:** I didn't change the **schema** file I let it as default.

Comment: Special characters will usually end up splitting a word/etc. into multiple tokens when indexing; if you then try to search for tokens (i.e. verbatim searching for those characters), they will not be present and can't be matched. When you say you don't get the expected result, you're going to have to give details about _what you expect_. Also be aware that _wildcard searches_ will usually not have most filters applied (except for those that are multiterm aware), so analysis doesn't happen in that case. This doesn't seem to be a python issue, but a plain Solr analysis/matching issue.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for your answer, I think my problem is in the tokenizer, I'll try to change the tokenizer that I use and check if the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problems by using the [tokenizers](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html) and [filters](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html) in indexing and querying.
You can use them by the [Client API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/using-python.html#using-python) that Solr provide.
Here is an example of JSON data to add tokenizers and filters to a field type:

```
{
    "replace-field-type": {
        "name": "field_name",
        "class": "solr.TextField",
        "multiValued": True,
        "indexAnalyzer": {
            "tokenizer": {
                "class": "solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"
            },
            "filters": [
                {
                    "class": "solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"
                }
            ]
        },
        "queryAnalyzer": {
            "tokenizer": {
                "class": "solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory",
                "rule": "java"
            },
            "filters": [
                {
                    "class": "solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```